# Inconsistent Reflection.Emit support in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, reflection.emit

I've been working on a compiler for a custom language for .NET, its currently using System.Reflection.Emit but when I want to run it on Mono (It runs fine on MS .NET, both 2.0 and 4.0 CLRs) I run into a bunch of exceptions when dealing with GenericTypeParameterBuilder, most specifically this one:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module.
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.check_created () [0x00012] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection.Emit\TypeBuilder.cs:1678 
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.InternalResolve () [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection.Emit\TypeBuilder.cs:1653 
at System.Reflection.Emit.GenericTypeParameterBuilder.InternalResolve () [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection.Emit\GenericTypeParameterBuilder.cs:93 
at System.Reflection.MonoGenericClass.InternalResolve () [0x00021] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection\MonoGenericClass.cs:105 
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor (MethodAttributes attributes) [0x00030] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection.Emit\TypeBuilder.cs:484 
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType () [0x0017f] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.10.9\mcs\class\corlib\System.Reflection.Emit\TypeBuilder.cs:788 
at dotC.CType.CreateType () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at dotC.Compiler.Save () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at dotC.Compiler.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at dotC.Dev.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Now the code that runs this is pretty involved so it is hard to copy-paste a specific piece of code, but the code structure I am trying to compile looks like this:

```
public class Foo<T> { }
public class Bar<T> : Foo<T> { }
```

And the problem happens when I am trying to compile the Bar<T> class which is supposed to inherit from Foo<T> where the generic parameter supplied to Foo is the T from bar.

So my question is: Is this a known issue in Mono SRE? Is there a way to work around this? Is it fixed in a new beta of mono or something, etc.?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: There are a number of reflection.emit issues mentioned in the mono-dev list. I'm sure this is just something they haven't gotten around to yet. You may have better luck on the dev list in terms of finding a workaround which, I'm almost sure there will be one, but I'm equally sure I won't know what it is.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly looks like a bug.  It appears that explicitly calling `DefineDefaultConstructor` on the child type's type builder prior to setting the parent type and calling `CreateType` will work around it, at least in the simplest case.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, explicitly defining a constructor for the child type (which potentially just calls the base constructor and returns) looks like it works even after setting the parent type, so that may be a better approach.

Comment: I have also run into fishiness as well with Mono and it's handling of default constructors.

Comment: Creating the default constructors for ALL involved types manually works perfectly!

Comment: this is a workaround anyway, you should file the bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this issue on the latest mono compiled from git and couldn't replicate this problem. It's possible it has already been fixed. The code I used:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    new AssemblyName("test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("test.dll");
var foo = module.DefineType("Foo");
foo.DefineGenericParameters("T");
var bar = module.DefineType("Bar");
bar.DefineGenericParameters("T");
bar.SetParent(foo);
foo.CreateType();
bar.CreateType();
```